# Connecting Pepper aldebaran robot to a wifi when there is no LAN cable available

Tags: pepper

Yesterday, I have come across a situation where I had to demo something on Pepper. However, I didn't have the LAN cable with me that time and I couldn't connect it to the Local WIFI there.

I know the procedure to connect to the WIFI with LAN cable using this procedure ( http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/family/pepper_user_guide/connecting_pep.html ). I couldn't access the Pepper's Page because I need to be atleast connected to some WIFI to change the WIFI connection in Pepper to some other WIFI connection.

Can someone let me know if there is a way to connect to the WIFI in pepper when there is no LAN cable? For example , may be, open the settings in the tab and connecting it to the WIFI?

Can anyone let me know if there is a solution to connect Pepper to a WIFI when there is no LAN cable and it's a new place where

Comment: By saying 'launch/run settings'? This prompts her settings on the tablet including the wifi.

Comment: If you don't have basic channel installed, or you use Pepper with unsupported language (basic channel's perspective), then either make your own "run settings" collaborative dialog for that language or make Pepper remember a shared network from your phone. You need to have a way to command the robot. It's either via LAN, WIFI or via collaborative dialog or other pre-installed app. There's really no other way, as you need to start boot-config/. behavior to get the robot settings on pepper's tablet, or access the robot web page hosted in robot.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "run/start/launch settings" to Pepper and this will open the settings menu, where you can set the WiFi connection.